# How to avoid creating a new tab at launching google chrome by UIApplication.shared.open?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-chrome

My application launches Google Chrome with the below code:

```
let url = URL(string: "googlechrome://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
```

But Chrome creates a new tab each time at launching.
I want to launch that URL at the same tab.

It seems that in the past there was a "create-new-tab" option to control whether to create tabs.
https://github.com/googlearchive/OpenInChrome/tree/785a1092ee3f954eab09bd2e6abdc46a7b2bc190

Currently, a new tab is created by default.
Does anyone know a good way?

Comment: Why would you want to override the current tab? Seems like a bad user experience if my tabs got overridden.

Comment: @HarryJ
  
Thanks for your confirmation.  
  
My application's scenario is:  
1. My application receives push notification when customer issue request.  
2. Request list page will open with Chrome when staff tap notification.  
  
After tapping several notifications, the same page (request list) will be displayed many times in staff's browser.  
  
I know it's better to use WebView in this case, but I'd like to implement it in a pure Chrome browser at this time.